# How can I re-order the children of my container in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, programming-languages

I have a little trouble in managing the children my container. The fact is that it has a lot of children and their y coordinates are very random.

Is there anyway i can order them by y coordinates that the lower will be in the front and the higher with be in the back?

is it something that that I can do with 2 "for"?

Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//the number of elements in our component
var count:int = numElements;
var elements:Array = [];

//load all the elements of the component into an Array
for (var i:int=0; i<count; i++) {
    elements[i] = getElementAt(i);
}

//sort the Array elements based on their 'y' property
elements.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC);

//re-add the element to the component 
//in the order of the sorted Array we just created.
//When we add the element using 'addElement' it will 
//be added at the top of the component's displaylist
//and will automatically be removed from its original position.
for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
    addElement(elements[i]);
}
```

This is for Spark components. You can do the exact same thing with mx components using `getChildAt()` and `addChild()` instead of `getElementAt()` and `addElement()`

Comment: Of course var elements:Array = [count]; is wrong, it should have been
var elements:Array = new Array(count);
yet that is useless too, it will also work like:
var elements:Array = [];

Answer (score 1):

This assumes your container is named `container` and exists in the same scope as the code (untested):

```
//prepare an array
var sortArray:Array = [];
//put the children into an array
for(var i:int = 0; i < container.numChildren; i++) {
    sortArray[i] = container.getChildAt(i);
}
//get a sorting function ready
function depthSort(a:MovieClip,b:MovieClip):int
{
    return a.y - b.y;
}
//sort the array by y value low -> high
sortArray.sort(depthSort);
//loop through the array resetting indexes
for(i = 0; i <sortArray.length; i++) {
    container.setChildIndex(sortArray[i],i);
}
```

Comment: We seem to think rather simultaneously ;) That's the second time in two days.

Comment: Yours was neater all round though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the stacking order to be sorted with respect to `y`.

You can use this method:

```
addChildAt(child:DisplayObject, index:int)
```

Where an index of zero represents the bottom of the DisplayList and `numChildren - 1` represents the top.

Check the AS3 language reference for more details: [flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt%28%29)

Comment: thank you, but could you be more detail? since the y are randomly created, I cannot know the value of the index.

Comment: Sure! It looks like others have beaten me to it. Essentially, you would have to place the children in an array, perform a sort with respect to y, and then reorder the DisplayObjects using the respective indexes in the sorted array.