# As3 - Target all MovieClips?

Tags: actionscript-3, target, movieclip

I was wondering if there is any way to target all MovieClips, so I can for example add effects to all of them.. Would

```
for each(Mc:MovieClip in stage){
//do sth
}
```

work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish it was as simple as your suggestion, it would certainly make more sense. Unfortunately, you probably need to do something more like the following:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
{
    var m:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);
    if(m is MovieClip)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

This will loop through all the children then check if they are a movieclip, then you can do your stuff.

Alternately you could track every movieclip as it's added to the stage in an array, then reference from that. But that possibly just overkill. Depends on your use case.

Comment: Hmm, yea i see i will try it, btw do you know how can i fix the problem when my MovieClip stays on top?

Comment: Here gives a good explanation how to accomplish that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667867/how-can-i-re-order-the-children-of-my-container-in-as3

Comment: If it doesn't you should make another question / search stack overflow for the answer best for your scenario. Don't forget to accept the answer thats correct for you

Comment: Yea, ok :) btw won't this for method use a lot of memory if i want to make it continuosly?

Comment: Perhaps, but its still application overhead you probably don't need, it depends how many items you're looping through, and how often. A few questions... How many times would you use this? why are you looping over these objects? And how many objects do you think you'll be looping through?

Comment: Like, 6 times x turn (30 sec). I'm looping over these objects so if I have an attack spell, it  makes all blurry, only the opponent not.. Like 10 objects